# Identification of a Subset to a Point

Tags: elementary-set-theory, equivalence-relations

If $A$ is a subspace of a topological space $S$, we can define a relation $∼$ on S by
declaring
$$x ∼ x\quad\text{for all}\quad x\in S$$
(so the relation is reflexive) and
$$x ∼ y\quad\text{for all}\quad x, y\in A.$$

> **Question 1.** On the book it says that this is an equivalence relation on $S$. Why?
>
> **Question 2.** Who are the equivalence classes?

Thanks!

Comment: Short 1) $x,y,z \in A$

Comment: I am not sure about the downvote, but I guess it is because you didn't show "efforts" in your question, for example by explaining which axiom of equivalences you have problems to check in Question 1.

Comment: @Taladris I can't see how this could be an equivalence relation. Reflexivity is clear by definition, but already symmetry I can't see it.

Comment: Just think for a bit, and handle cases.  If $x \sim y$ then either $x=y$ and symmetry is obvious, or $x \neq y$ and then $x, y \in A$.  But if $x$ and $y$ both live in $A$, then $y$ and $x$ both live in $A$....

Comment: You should mention it in your question I think. Symmetry is obvious: if $x\sim y$, then either $x=y$ or ($x$ and $y$ are in $A$). This implies that $y=x$ or ($y$ and $x$ are in $A$), so $y\sim x$. For transitivity, it is no more difficult, but you need to consider cases.

Comment: @Taladris Thanks! I understood. Then passing to the equivalence classes, if $x\in X$, then $[x]=x$, while if $x\in A$, then $[x]=A$, right?

Comment: @JackJ.  You would say that if $x \in A$ then $[x]=A$ and if $x \in X - A$ then $[x]=\{x\}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the definitions to see it is an equivalence relation:

- reflexivity is given.
- If $x \sim y$ then either we're in the case $x \sim x$ (option 1) and so $y=x$ and $y \sim x$ is again given. Or we're in the case $x,y \in A$ and so then also $y \sim x$. The statement $x\in A \land y \in A$ is symmetric in $x$ and $y$.
- For proofs of transitivity we can always assume WLOG that all three points involved are different: in this case $x \sim y$ and $y\sim z$ then implies $x,y\in A$ and $y,z\in A$, so clearly also $x,z\in A$ (we jus state less info) so $x \sim z$.

The equivalence classes of course are $A$ and all $\{x\}$ where $x \notin A$.
So $A$ becomes a new point in the quotient space and all other are left untouched.